# how to select a row in a table according to checkbox column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Using Asp.net and `jQuery` I have a `GridView`  with a `CheckBox` column.  Right now I have code that highlights (green) a row whenever the mouse goes over it (and unhighlights (yellow) on mouse out).  I would like to add the ability to highlight it a different color (pink) whenever the checkbox in that row is checked.

My problem is that after checking the box and the row highlights pink, when I mouse out, the row returns to the original color (yellow).  How can I make the row with the checkbox not react to the mouse out code?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does your code look like?  Can you include a sample of what you have done, such as show your code for highlighting a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example code:

```
$( function() {
 $( 'tr' ).hover( 
  function() {
   $( this ).addClass( "hover-highlight" );
  },
  function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "hover-highlight" );
  }
 );
 $( 'tr.checkcolumn input' ).click( function() {
   $( this ).parents( "tr" ).addClass( "checked-highlight" );
 });
});
```

And some css:

```
tr { background-color: yellow; }
tr.hover-highlight { background-color: green; }
tr.checked-highlight { background-color: pink!important; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a css class something like "userSelected" to your selected row. Modify your css/code to show hilighther color or default color so that they will be applied only for the rows which doesn't contain "userSelected" css class.

Comment: you say: I use `:not(.class)` ?

Comment: Yes. You can use :not, or you can also do in other way. Add a css class called "NotSelected" for all non selected rows and apply your highligh and default colors for all rows which contains the "NotSelected" css class. When a row is selected, remove the "NotSelected" class for the selected row.